# WPF: VM-first, close Window in a MVVM-conform way

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, syncfusion

in my application I'm opening a Window for an Input form. In my App.xaml I have defined the following:

```
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:EditTicketViewModel}">
                <Frame>
                    <Frame.Content>
                        <Views:EditTicketView></Views:EditTicketView>
                    </Frame.Content>
                </Frame>
            </DataTemplate>
```

My application also has a Window service for opening windows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DevPortal.Interfaces
{
    public interface IWindowService
    {
        public void ShowWindow(object viewModel, bool showDialog);
    }
}
```

the implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using DevPortal.Interfaces;
using Syncfusion.Windows.Shared;
using Syncfusion.SfSkinManager;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace DevPortal.Services
{
    public class WindowService : IWindowService
    {
        public void ShowWindow(object viewModel, bool showDialog)
        {
            var window = new ChromelessWindow();
            window.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
            SfSkinManager.SetTheme(window, new Theme("FluentDark"));
            window.Content = viewModel;
            window.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
            window.Title = viewModel.GetType().GetProperty("Title").GetValue(viewModel).ToString();
            window.ShowIcon = false;

            if (showDialog)
            {
                window.ShowDialog();
            } else
            {
                window.Show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

How I open the window (from a viewmodel in the MainView)

```
    [RelayCommand]
    private void CreateTicket()
    {
        App.Current.ServiceProvider.GetService<IWindowService>().ShowWindow(new EditTicketViewModel(), true);
    }
```

What would be the best way to close this window from the ViewModel? Previously i was used to  directly create the view, and in the constructor of the view i would subscribe to a close-event in the viewmodel, but that's not really the MVVM-way I guess. Do I need to implement some kind of service? Thanks!

EDIT: I forgott to mention that the View is a page. So i Am creating a window with the viewmodel as content, and the datatemplate of the viewmodel is a Frame containing the page.

Comment: I use a specific class to implement navigation between pages. This handles things like pop-ups, navigation between pages (with data passing) and navigation stack. It has a dictionary of routes against view models and views. A ViewModel just calls a method to Navigate using a particular route. This way a ViewModel isn't tied to a destination ViewModel or View. On changing page it inserts the new ViewModel into the View constructor

Comment: In terms of MVVM, there is no way as the view model is not allowed to interact with view elements or to implement view related logic. From the view model point of view there is no UI. A nice solution is to let the related view model class expose a data model for your Window e.g. via a dedicated `DialogModel` property. Optionally, let the view model class raise a trusted property e.g. `DialogModelChanged`.

Comment: Your WindowSerivce must be used by the view e.g. MainWindow or any other view component. Then let this service observe the view model class that exposes the dialog model property/event and show the Window accordingly. The Window is then closed by the user explicitly or implicitly e.g. by clicking the "Ok" Button. The data is transferred to the dialog model bis data binding.

Comment: Since your view model exposes/controls the fishing model, it has ready access to its data.

Answer (score 1):

You could for example return an `IWindow` from your window service:

```
public class WindowService : IWindowService
{
    public IWindow ShowWindow(object viewModel, bool showDialog)
    {
        var window = new ChromelessWindow();
        ...
        return window;
    }
}
```

...and then simply call `Close()` on this one in the view model.

The interface would be as simple as this:

```
public interface IWindow
{
    void Close();
}
```

Your `ChromelessWindow` implements the interface:

```
public partial class ChromelessWindow : Window, IWindow { ... }
```

...and the view model only has a dependency on an interface. It still doesn't know anything about a view or actual window. `IWindow` is just a name. I can be called anything.

Comment: You are talking about class level dependencies and dependency inversion here. On application level, why would the view model be interested in a logic that explicitly closes a or handles a view component?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way of closing a Window from it's ViewModel is using an attached property.

```
public static class perWindowHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseWindowProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CloseWindow",
        typeof(bool?),
        typeof(perWindowHelper),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCloseWindowChanged));

    private static void OnCloseWindowChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!(target is Window view))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (view.IsModal())
        {
            view.DialogResult = args.NewValue as bool?;
        }
        else
        {
            view.Close();
        }
    }

    public static void SetCloseWindow(Window target, bool? value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CloseWindowProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool IsModal(this Window window)
    {
        var fieldInfo = typeof(Window).GetField("_showingAsDialog", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        return fieldInfo != null && (bool)fieldInfo.GetValue(window);
    }
}
```

In the ViewModel create a ViewClosed property

```
private bool? _viewClosed;

public bool? ViewClosed
{
    get => _viewClosed;
    set => Set(nameof(ViewClosed), ref _viewClosed, value);
}
```

then in the View, bind to it using the attached property

```
<Window
    ...
    vhelp:perWindowHelper.CloseWindow="{Binding ViewClosed}" >
```

Mode details on my take on MVVM navigation on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-navigation/).